# Matching table (with sub-tables) to another table(with sub-tables) efficiently

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a problem in an ETL process. I need to integrate data into a data warehouse. The data is associated with a "variant". A variant is defined as having a specific set of parameters (identified by a property bag table with name and value, both varchar).

For example:

```
Variant 1
  Field A value 11
  Field B Value 22
Variant 2
  Field A value 12
  Field B value 23
```

A simplified table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [simstg].[Parameter](
    [VariantNo] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Variable] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Parameter] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [VariantNo] ASC,
    [Variable] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

I need to import those variants (and the number can not be changed) from staging tables into a final resting table. THere we do have similar Variant Numbers, but the numbers DO NOT MATCH UP. So I need to map the variants. Variant 1 from the staging tables may be variant 22 in the final tables, or may not exist (in which case I create a new variant number).

I am stuck trying to identify the variants, efficiently. I know I am looking for a variant number in the target table that has the same number of parameters, with every parameter having the exact same value. You can assume the table s are identical - I can take it from there.

I know I can do that with a cursor - but going through every variant in the target table is prohibitive expensive. I know I can also generate a key string on the client side (or via a SP) and / or put a hashcode on that one and store them (which could happen SQL side). I could use dynamic SQL to basically generate a parameter string, then use HasHBytes on top of it to get a hash - then compare hashes to rule out most of the data.

But is there a more efficient way?